# Using boost to handle COM variants

Tags: c++, boost, com

I'm working with a c++ project that has a lot of COM functions. The majority of the inputs and outputs are VARIANTs. Is there an easy way to serialize/deserialize these into long, string, etc using Boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost has absolutely nothing with regards to Microsoft's COM technology. The closest thing to COM's variant in Boost would be [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html). You can write COM's `variant_t` to `boost::any` converter, then you can serialize, cast etc.

Comment: So you're saying that I can do it, but I have to write the conversion function using OLE2A, etc.

Comment: @JWM: Yes, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: What about boost::lexical_cast? Can I use that instead? I tried it to convert from BSTR to int (works), but couldn't get BSTR to string.

Comment: @JWM: Lexical cast doesn't know anything about COM's variant. But you can throw in few extra lines of code to support it. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source OPC (OLE for Process Control) server implementation called FatRat library. It uses boost and pushes a lot of VARIANTs around. Very inspirational.